# Can I install Arch Linux without internet?

Tags: arch-linux

I want to install Arch Linux but I haven't internet with fast speed ! In one time I download the official ISO file and started installation and I saw CLI not GUI and I started read documentation and there we must put repository and download some files ! My question is can I install Arch Linux without internet connection with ISO file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but if you want a graphical environment without downloading anything, it would be easier for you to install a distro like Manjaro (which is based on Arch Linux).

Answer (score 1):

When installing Arch Linux use the -c flag when running pacstrap. This won't help you that much though because youll likely need many more packages anyway. Make sure to install the minimum needed for a chroot then download the rest chrooted. Then you can copy everything in pacmans cache to use on another system.